# Why is it necessary to go to the reputation tab to clear my reputation notifications?

Tags: discussion, reputation, profile-page, notifications, top-bar

I can see very easily, using the "Achievements" button on the top bar, how much reputation I've just earned and where I earned it.

But in my profile, the "new reputation" notification will persist until I go to the "reputation" tab to clear it. I'm not sure if there is an expiry timer on the notification, I haven't tested this, but I'd prefer the profile notification to go away after I've viewed it in the top bar.

I guess it's a preference thing, but I feel like I'm clearing each notification twice.

Comment: All of your profile notifications are _"sticky"_. I find this useful, because I'm using different devices to access SO. From time to time I go to my profile and review and clear them.

Answer (score 1):

If someone has reputation gains on multiple sites they may not want it to clear until they visit their profile on that site. When clicking the Achievement button in the top bar it clears it for all sites which does not mean that you have viewed the information you want for all your sites.